# How to install the cloud foundry from the downloaded folder from github?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have downloaded the cloud foundry download folder from git hub however i am not able to install as I cant find a suitable file to execute or run in this folder. Kindly please help!

Comment: What did you download exactly? Did you download a CloudFoundry release?

Comment: Hi I had downloaded the zip file from gitHub

Comment: that zip you downloaded is supposed to be a [BOSH release](http://bosh.io/) which is intended to be deployed against a certain IaaS. You need to write your manifest to do so. I'm afraid It's not an one-click task